# The RJ45 Ethernet only has pins 2, 4, 6 and 8 terminated. How can I solve this?

Tags: ethernet, pin

I just moved into a condo, they have Ethernet running to each room.  I couldn't get it to work meaning when I plugged my router to distribute internet to each room from the distribution box, the other end did not detect a connection.

I bought a wire tracker, JW-360 and discover only pins 2 4 6 and 8 appear send and receive a signal for all the rooms. Any reason for them to do that? All the rooms only are able to send and receive signals on these pins. Any suggestions?

My setup is fiber optic model to google nest router to D-Link route. The D-Link router is used to distribute internet via wiring to all the rooms.

I've uploaded some videos/pictures of me using the wire tracker.  Use the below link.

I don’t know that they are compliant to Ethernet (IEEE 802.3).

Its fairly straight forward how to use a JW-360, I don’t see another use case but please correct me if I am wrong.

The condo is separately wired for ethernet and telephone.

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMmSFz1suskKBQlrodFCgnrv1E8zMpCKuHjFs_FGuCKaCFenlTVLBu_8ibFBHIH1Q/photo/AF1QipNFn-zLKB2KsqTiRKOunsUSbz2B_QxtappCe546?key=bXp0bUVCRC1aYkg1OUR1bkRETXFKeFVuSmxNbVV3

Comment: What kind of wire tracer are we talking about? Base-T Ethernet cabling isn't terminated at all. A wire tracer isn't the right tool to test Ethernet cabling, a cable tester is. If one knows how to do it, a multimeter works but is inconvenient. 10Base-T and 100Base-T cabling only uses 4 out of 8 wires, but the ones used are 1-3 and 6. The fact that there's in-built cabling doesn't mean there's internet connectivity, so what exactly do you mean when you say you "couldn't get it to work"? How did you try? Please don't answer in a comment, edit your question instead to update it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've updated my original post

Comment: How do you know those outlets are compliant with Ethernet (IEEE 802.3)? As @Peregrino69 noted standard LAN cabling uses pins 1, 2, 3, and 6. See https://satoms.com/ethernet-cable-pinouts/. I've never used a JW-360. Since you bought one for this issue I have to assume you are using one for the first time. In which case it is somewhat likely you have made a mistake in its correct use.

Comment: That works. 2, 4, 6, 8 lighting up is most likely an error message; you need both devices to test the cabling. How to: plug the Emitter with a known good cable to the same outlet where you plan to connect your router, and flip the switch to `Test` position. Take the Receiver, plug it with a cable to another outlet and press `Test`. If LEDs 1, 2, 3 and 6 light up _or_ if all LEDs light up except for G, the cable is healthy and supports 10/100Mb/s networking. If all LEDs light up _including_ G, the cable is healthy and supports Gigabit networking.

Comment: If only 2, 4, 6 and 8 light up when this is correctly used, there's just 3 possibilities: 1) it's not wired for Ethernet but telephone use 2) it's wired incorrectly (unlikely - this'd been tested and fixed at the building stage) 3) the tester's battery is out or it's broken

Comment: I’ve uploaded some additional pics and video to illustrate how I am using the tester.  Its pretty simple.  I didn’t want to start re-wiring because its not my place, I am only renting.  I wanted to try and understand why someone would wire an entire condo like this….seems very odd.

Comment: The photos show text "SIP", which is abbreviation of [Session Initiation Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol); used in voice, video and messaging. I believe what you're looking at is actually digital phone cabling

Comment: @Peregrino69, thats right, for those 3 ports it is SIP.  All the "D" ports should have been ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're satisfied with 100 Mbit/s Ethernet *and* the cable is of the right grade (twisted pair, at least Category 5) then you'll need to rewire.

Ethernet 10/100 (10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX) require the 1-2 and 3-6 pairs to work. The pairs need to be twisted together and transport the required frequencies. Check whether it's properly twisted and Cat 5 at least. You'll need to either use a good cable tester (800+ €) or open up the wall jacks and inspect visually.

*If* the cable is a proper grade, you need to either rewire the wall jacks or crimp an adapter cable for each one.

If the cable is just voice grade (unmarked but twisted) you could try if it (somewhat) works for 100BASE-TX. For short runs (<10 m) you might just get away with it. In theory, you could also use VDSL converters/bridges for up to 300 Mbit/s - however, that's a *very* expensive approach, by purchase price and power usage both.

If all that is out of your league or 100 Mbit/s is too slow anyway, forget about the cabling.

For why they made this strangely wired cabling you'll have to ask your landlord/the previous owner.